# ClangTidy + CMake - ignore third party headers from Conan

Tags: c++, cmake, c++20, conan, clang-tidy

I am trying to use ClangTidy on some working source code but I cannot get it to ignore / bypass `lib{fmt}` and see lots of noise such as:

~/.conan/data/fmt/9.1.0/*/*/package/2c09c8f84c016041549fcee94e4caae5d89424b6/
include/fmt/core.h:2955:15: warning: 5 uninitialized fields at the end of
the constructor call [clang-analyzer-optin.cplusplus.UninitializedObject]
types_{
^
~/.conan/data/fmt/9.1.0/*/*/package/2c09c8f84c016041549fcee94e4caae5d89424b6/
include/fmt/core.h:732:7: note: uninitialized field
'this->context_.num_args_'
int num_args_;
^~~~~~~~~

I am using CMake + Conan and the diagnostic messages I have come from `lib{fmt}`.

How can I silence them? For CppCheck it was simply a case of specifying that all files under `~/.conan/` should be ignored.

**How do I tell Clang-tidy to ignore all files under** `~/.conan/`

**Note I have seen [clang-tidy - ignore third party headers code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61101056/clang-tidy-ignore-third-party-headers-code) which does not answer my question**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

System header files do not generate warnings. You need to mark the fmt header-files as system header-files.

NOTE: I am using cmake and CPMAddPackage() to bring fmt into my build environment, your millage my vary:

```
CPMAddPackage("gh:fmtlib/fmt#10.1.1")
```

This defines the cmake-variable `FMT_SOURCE_DIR` which points to the location of the header files. Use this variable to set-up the fmt include:

```
include_directories(
  SYSTEM
  ${FMT_SOURCE_DIR}/include)
```

This fixed the issue for me. Your setup may create a different variable for exactly the same purpose. You can consult [SO answer, about printing all variables,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9298278/cmake-print-out-all-accessible-variables-in-a-script/9328525#9328525) to find the name of the variable you need.